# Trying to use multiple arrays to find a team's recent form

Tags: javascript

Ok so I'm making a league system and am trying to find the recent form for each team using a function that takes in the team id and then outputs their last 5 matches in terms of W (for win) D (for tie) and L (for Loss). I have a very large fixture list that I did not include for simplicity. It's got the week number, like week 14, homeId, awayId, homescore and awayscore which I'm using to find the recent form, but what outputs doesn't match the actual recent form and I'm stumped as to why.

Edit, I'll include the first week of the fixtures array

```
var teams = [
 {id: 1, name: "AC Milan", GP:0, W: 0, D: 0, L:0, GF:0, GA:0, pts:0},
 {id: 2, name: "AS Roma", GP:0, W: 0, D: 0, L:0, GF:0, GA:0, pts:0},
 {id: 3, name: "Atalanta", GP:0, W: 0, D: 0, L:0, GF:0, GA:0, pts:0},
 {id: 4, name: "Bologna", GP:0, W: 0, D: 0, L:0, GF:0, GA:0, pts:0},
 {id: 5, name: "Benevento", GP:0, W: 0, D: 0, L:0, GF:0, GA:0, pts:0},
 {id: 6, name: "Cagliari", GP:0, W: 0, D: 0, L:0, GF:0, GA:0, pts:0},
 {id: 7, name: "Chievo", GP:0, W: 0, D: 0, L:0, GF:0, GA:0, pts:0},
 {id: 8, name: "Crotone", GP:0, W: 0, D: 0, L:0, GF:0, GA:0, pts:0},
 {id: 9, name: "Fiorentina", GP:0, W: 0, D: 0, L:0, GF:0, GA:0, pts:0},
 {id: 10, name: "Genoa", GP:0, W: 0, D: 0, L:0, GF:0, GA:0, pts:0},
 {id: 11, name: "Hellas Verona", GP:0, W: 0, D: 0, L:0, GF:0, GA:0, pts:0},
 {id: 12, name: "Inter", GP:0, W: 0, D: 0, L:0, GF:0, GA:0, pts:0},
 {id: 13, name: "Juventus", GP:0, W: 0, D: 0, L:0, GF:0, GA:0, pts:0},
 {id: 14, name: "Lazio", GP:0, W: 0, D: 0, L:0, GF:0, GA:0, pts:0},
 {id: 15, name: "Napoli", GP:0, W: 0, D: 0, L:0, GF:0, GA:0, pts:0},
 {id: 16, name: "Sampdoria", GP:0, W: 0, D: 0, L:0, GF:0, GA:0, pts:0},
 {id: 17, name: "Sassuolo", GP:0, W: 0, D: 0, L:0, GF:0, GA:0, pts:0},
 {id: 18, name: "SPAL", GP:0, W: 0, D: 0, L:0, GF:0, GA:0, pts:0},
 {id: 19, name: "Torino", GP:0, W: 0, D: 0, L:0, GF:0, GA:0, pts:0},
{id: 20, name: "Udinese", GP:0, W: 0, D: 0, L:0, GF:0, GA:0, pts:0},
];

var fixtures = [
//matchday1
{match: 1, week: 1, Homeid: 13, Awayid: 6,    Homescore: 3, Awayscore: 0},
{match: 1, week: 1, Homeid: 11, Awayid: 15,    Homescore: 1, Awayscore: 3},
{match: 1, week: 1, Homeid: 3,  Awayid: 2,    Homescore: 0, Awayscore: 1},
{match: 1, week: 1, Homeid: 14, Awayid: 18,   Homescore: 0, Awayscore: 0},
{match: 1, week: 1, Homeid: 4,  Awayid: 19,   Homescore: 1, Awayscore: 1},
{match: 1, week: 1, Homeid: 12, Awayid: 9,     Homescore: 3, Awayscore: 0},
{match: 1, week: 1, Homeid: 20, Awayid: 7,    Homescore: 1, Awayscore: 2},
{match: 1, week: 1, Homeid: 16, Awayid: 5,   Homescore: 2, Awayscore: 1},
{match: 1, week: 1, Homeid: 17, Awayid: 10,   Homescore: 0, Awayscore: 0},
{match: 1, week: 1, Homeid: 8, Awayid: 1,   Homescore: 0, Awayscore:3 },
//matchday2 etc it goes on until 
];

  for (var i = 0; i < fixtures.length;i++) {    //For loop which calculates the Home and Away results for each team
    if (fixtures[i].Homescore != null){
    // Hometeam
    teams[fixtures[i].Homeid-1].GP+=fixtures[i].match;            //for example ac milan is id 1, but in team array they occupy [0] spot, so team[fixtures[i].homeid -1] would be 0 in the team array but have home id 1 in the fixture array
    teams[fixtures[i].Homeid-1].GF+=fixtures[i].Homescore;
    teams[fixtures[i].Homeid-1].GA+=fixtures[i].Awayscore;
    teams[fixtures[i].Homeid-1].GD+=fixtures[i].Homescore-fixtures[i].Awayscore;
    teams[fixtures[i].Homeid-1].W+=fixtures[i].Homescore > fixtures[i].Awayscore ? 1 : 0;
    teams[fixtures[i].Homeid-1].L+=fixtures[i].Homescore < fixtures[i].Awayscore ? 1 : 0;
    teams[fixtures[i].Homeid-1].D+=fixtures[i].Homescore == fixtures[i].Awayscore ? 1 : 0;
    // Awayteam
    teams[fixtures[i].Awayid-1].GP+=fixtures[i].match;
    teams[fixtures[i].Awayid-1].GF+=fixtures[i].Awayscore;
    teams[fixtures[i].Awayid-1].GA+=fixtures[i].Homescore;
    teams[fixtures[i].Awayid-1].GD+=fixtures[i].Awayscore-fixtures[i].Homescore;
    teams[fixtures[i].Awayid-1].W+=fixtures[i].Homescore < fixtures[i].Awayscore ? 1 : 0;
    teams[fixtures[i].Awayid-1].L+=fixtures[i].Homescore > fixtures[i].Awayscore ? 1 : 0;
    teams[fixtures[i].Awayid-1].D+=fixtures[i].Homescore == fixtures[i].Awayscore ? 1 : 0;
    }
}



function Form(id){                   ///////////Finds the League form of each team //////////////
var form = "";
var one = "";
var two = "";
var three = "";
var four = "";
var five = "";
var last_five = [];
var new_fixtures = [];
var formContainer = document.querySelector("#form");

   teams.sort(function(a,b){
    var n = a.id - b.id;
    if (n !== 0){
        return n;
    }
});


for (var i = 0; i < fixtures.length; i++){
    if (teams[id - 1].GP == fixtures[i].week && fixtures[i].Homeid == teams[id - 1].id){
        if (fixtures[i].Homescore > fixtures[i].Awayscore){
            one = "W";
        }
        else if (fixtures[i].Homescore == fixtures[i].Awayscore){
            one = "D";
        }
        else if (fixtures[i].Homescore < fixtures[i].Awayscore){
            one = "L";
        }
    }

    if (teams[id - 1].GP == fixtures[i].week && fixtures[i].Awayid == teams[id - 1].id){
        if (fixtures[i].Homescore < fixtures[i].Awayscore){
            one = "L";
        }
        else if (fixtures[i].Homescore == fixtures[i].Awayscore){
            one = "D";
        }
        else if (fixtures[i].Homescore > fixtures[i].Awayscore){
            one = "W";
        }
    }

    if ((teams[id - 1].GP - 1) == fixtures[i].week && fixtures[i].Homeid == teams[id - 1].id){
        if (fixtures[i].Homescore > fixtures[i].Awayscore){
            two = "W";
        }
        else if (fixtures[i].Homescore == fixtures[i].Awayscore){
            two = "D";
        }
        else if (fixtures[i].Homescore < fixtures[i].Awayscore){
            two = "L";
        }
    }

    if ((teams[id - 1].GP - 1) == fixtures[i].week && fixtures[i].Awayid == teams[id - 1].id){
        if (fixtures[i].Homescore < fixtures[i].Awayscore){
            two = "L";
        }
        else if (fixtures[i].Homescore == fixtures[i].Awayscore){
            two = "D";
        }
        else if (fixtures[i].Homescore > fixtures[i].Awayscore){
            two = "W";
        }
    }

   if ((teams[id - 1].GP-2) == fixtures[i].week && fixtures[i].Homeid == teams[id - 1].id){
        if (fixtures[i].Homescore > fixtures[i].Awayscore){
            three = "W";
        }
        else if (fixtures[i].Homescore == fixtures[i].Awayscore){
            three = "D";
        }
        else if (fixtures[i].Homescore < fixtures[i].Awayscore){
            three = "L";
        }
    }

    if ((teams[id - 1].GP-2) == fixtures[i].week && fixtures[i].Awayid == teams[id - 1].id){
        if (fixtures[i].Homescore < fixtures[i].Awayscore){
            three = "L";
        }
        else if (fixtures[i].Homescore == fixtures[i].Awayscore){
            three = "D";
        }
        else if (fixtures[i].Homescore > fixtures[i].Awayscore){
            three = "W";
        }
    }
```

And so on and so on until I get the last 5 matches played

```
last_five = [one, two, three, four, five];

form = "<h4>" + "Form: " + last_five + "</h4>";

formContainer.innerHTML += form;

 }
```

Comment: What part of it is not working correctly? Have you debugged it line per line? 
Dumping code in SO and asking why the whole dump isn't working is not ideal. :)

Comment: your javascript has error. can you fix it?

Comment: No, my javascript works. I only posted half of it as it just continues until it checks the last 5 fixtures. Its that it's printing the wrong form. The placements of W L and D seem random

Comment: Have you debugged that? Create a breakpoint and check the value of your conditions in console. Check why your conditions are not returning what you expect.

Comment: Ah you are a student, this looks to be a homework?
Try creating breakpoints then check each condition value. If the value before the condition is wrong, then check why that is wrong, repeat until you find the issue. I'm not familiar with "home" and "away" and what they mean in sports, so I can't connect with the problem in a personal level. :)

You can also create a fiddle, it makes it easier to get an answer if a working revision of the problem is at hand.

Comment: nah, personal project. But ya I should be utilizing the debugger/breakpoints